# Inserting pandas dataframe values into postgresql table with partitioned fail

Tags: pandas, postgresql

DDL:

```
create table if not exists stock_kr.ticker (
    code VARCHAR,
    full_code VARCHAR,
    name VARCHAR,
    market VARCHAR,
    category_sector VARCHAR,
    close INTEGER,
    open INTEGER,
    high INTEGER,
    low INTEGER,
    volume BIGINT,
    volume_price BIGINT,
    market_cap BIGINT,
    num_share BIGINT,
    date_time TIMESTAMP with time zone
)
partition by RANGE (date_time);
```

Code:

```
In [11]: df.dtypes
Out[11]:
code                       string
full_code                  string
name                       string
market                     string
category_sector            string
close                       Int64
open                        Int64
high                        Int64
low                         Int64
volume                      Int64
volume_price                Int64
market_cap                  Int64
num_share                   Int64
date_time          datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

In [12]: df.head(1).to_sql(
    ...:     schema="stock_kr",
    ...:     name="ticker",
    ...:     con="postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432",
    ...:     if_exists='append',
    ...:     index=False,
    ...:     method="multi",
    ...: )
```

Error:

```
IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.CheckViolation) no partition of relation "ticker" found for row
DETAIL:  Partition key of the failing row contains (date_time) = (2000-01-04 00:00:00+00).

[SQL: INSERT INTO stock_kr.ticker (code, full_code, name, market, category_sector, close, open, high, low, volume, volume_price, market_cap, num_share, date_time) VALUES (%(code_m0)s, %(full_code_m0)s, %(name_m0)s, %(market_m0)s, %(category_sector_m0)s, %(close_m0)s, %(open_m0)s, %(high_m0)s, %(low_m0)s, %(volume_m0)s, %(volume_price_m0)s, %(market_cap_m0)s, %(num_share_m0)s, %(date_time_m0)s)]
[parameters: {'code_m0': '008480', 'full_code_m0': 'KR7008480006', 'name_m0': 'KEP전자', 'market_m0': 'KOSPI', 'category_sector_m0': 'nan', 'close_m0': 2080, 'open_m0': 1920, 'high_m0': 2300, 'low_m0': 1915, 'volume_m0': 776620, 'volume_price_m0': 1598012100, 'market_cap_m0': 46344371840, 'num_share_m0': 22280948, 'date_time_m0': datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 4, 0, 0)}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
```

What did I missing?